# Install private NPM module from SVN

Tags: svn, npm, package-managers

#### Situation/Use case

I have several projects that share a build system. The build system uses gulp. Everything is version controlled in SVN repositories.

I'd like to create a NPM package (called `build`) containing my gulp tasks, in order to not copy the build system to every new project.

The gulp tasks are located in their own subdirectory of the SVN repository, which has its own `tags`, `branches` and `trunk` subfolders. The `build`-package contains its own `package.json` file.

#### Question:

How do I require a NPM package in a project, directly from SVN? I'd like to choose the tag and branch to use, and of course, the packages dependencies should be installed too.

#### What I have tried

Of course I have searched, but I've only found solutions that either

- Work only for git repositories
- Require me to set up my own NPM registry
- Cost money
- Install the dependencies of my `build`-package into the `build`-packages subfolder in `node_modules` (i.e. `gulp` is installed into `node_modules/build/node_modules/gulp`, not into `node_modules/gulp`)
- Do not work at all (result in an empty `node_modules` folder)

I've tried these npm packages so far: `npm-svn`, `svn-npm-crutch`, `svn-modules`. Neither really works (all don't install dependencies of the `build`-package correctly).

Comment: Hey Jost, I'm facing a similar problem. My I ask how you end up solving this? Thanks.

Comment: @Lucía I ended up installing a Nexus Repository server, and just register my modules in it. Still a PITA when requiring authentication (especially when forced to update ones passwords regularly), but it works.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll have to think about it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is still no better solution after 2 years and these plugins seems not too trustworthy